# Renaming column to previously existing column with different type won't let me update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Background: In a Java application I'm working on, I'm doing a refactoring of the storage of enum values. Previously, these were stored as integers, and mapped through enum values with a helper method in the enum. I would like to utilize the @EnumType.STRING capabilities of JPA to make the database more readable.

So, what I'm basically trying to do is change the type (as well as the values) of a column. For example, I had this table definition to begin with:

```
table Something (
    id int,
    source int,
    [more columns]
)
```

I wanted to change the source-column into a `VARCHAR(100)` column instead, and here is how I did that:

1. Introduce a new column, called source_new with VARCHAR(100).
2. Populate the new column with mapped values based on the values of the old column (so each row with value 1 in the source column get's the value 'SomeSource' in source_new, each row with value 2 in source gets 'OtherSource', and so on
3. Drop the source-column
4. Rename the source_new column to source (using sp_rename)

My problem is this: Once this is done, I can't update the now newly defined source-column, because it still insists that it's an int column, and not a varchar column!

So a query like this:

```
update Something set source = 'SomeSource' where id = 1;
```

fails with this:

```
Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SomeSource' to data type int.
SQLState:  22018
ErrorCode: 245
```

At the same time, sp_help of the table shows that the column is defined as varchar(100), and not int! Also, the column holds numerous varchar values from the original datamigration (from before the rename).

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong by renaming a column to a column name that was previously used with another type? (And as I'm typing the last question, it just sounds absurd to me, when I drop a column I expect to disappear, not to leave traces and in effect not allowing me to reuse the column name at any time in the future..)

SQLFiddle to illustrate (sp_rename doesn't work with SQLFiddle it seems): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0380f/3

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour, how are you executing your update query? In SSMS or through some application that might have the old schema cached?

Comment: I am using SQuirreL, but I have tried to both close the session and restart the program as a whole. I'll see if I can find any cache settings..

Comment: I've checked, and there is no caching enabled on the alias in question in SQuirreL. Also, it seems like that error comes from sqlserver itself, which is strange, because it is acknowledging that the column is a varchar column, but still treats it as an int column.. Can't seem to decide..

Comment: Have you tried sp_recompile?

Comment: No, but I've figured it out, I'll add an answer..

Comment: @Tobb I copied your code in SQLFiddle, and executed in my test sql database. It works.

Comment: I bet it does, since you don't have insane triggers scattered all over the place. Thx for the attempt :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the culprit, and it's name is trigger!

Some genious decided to put a check if the value updated is a valid source (checking against another table) in a trigger, so much for trusting your own code..

I spit on the shadow of people who hide functionality in database triggers, pfoy! Go back to the 80's where you belong! :p